# Loadash Debounce doesnt work as expected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

Heyr there !

i am trying to resolve one issue since long time , which is

1. I require a 2 seconds delay when user stops typing in any of input fields then i should call a function which makes an api call to update the form fields.
2. It should call the update function only once when user stopped typing after 2 seconds.

But it gives multiple API calls and i've tried using useCallback hooks but nothing worked out well.

Here's what i've tried so far :

```
import { debounce } from "lodash"


  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({})
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

 useEffect(() => {
    if (config.testing) {
      setProfile(config.testingProfile)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [profile])

  const getData = () => {
    axios.post(config.API_URL + 'users/address', {
      user: profile
    }).then(response => {
      setUser(response?.data?.data?.details)
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error?.response);
    })
  }

 const onPhoneNumberInput = (e) => {
    const input = e.target.value

    if (input?.length <= 11) {
      // setUser({ ...user, phoneNumber: input })
      onInputChange('phoneNumber', e.target.value);
    }
    if (input?.length < 10 && input?.length > 0) {
      setPhoneNumberError(true)
    }
    else {
      setPhoneNumberError(false)

    }
    
    
  }

  const onPostalCodeInput = (e) => {
    const input = e.target.value

    if (input?.length <= 7) {
      // setUser({ ...user, postalCode: input })
      onInputChange('postalCode', e.target.value);
    }
    if (input?.length < 7 && input?.length > 0) {
      setPostalCodeError(true)
    }
    else {
      setPostalCodeError(false)
    }
  }

  const onDone = useCallback(() => {
    if (phoneNumberError || postalCodeError) return;
    axios
      .post(config.API_URL + 'users/address/update', {
        user: profile,
        ...user,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status === 'success') {
          setSuccess(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setSuccess(null);
          }, 4000);
        }
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      });
  }, [phoneNumberError, postalCodeError, profile, user]);

  const onInputChange = (field, value) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [field]: value });
    optimizedInputChangeFn.cancel(); // clear the previous debounce timer
    optimizedInputChangeFn(); // set a new debounce timer
  };
  
  const optimizedInputChangeFn = useCallback(
    debounce(() => {
      onDone();
    }, 2000,[onDone]
  );
  

  useEffect(() => {
    optimizedInputChangeFn();
  }, [user, optimizedInputChangeFn]);


return (
 <p className="my-page-info-section-title">{t('SPOT.CONFIRM_NAME')}</p>

         <div className="form-input">
            <div className="row top gap px-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className={`user-info full ${!user?.nameKanji || !user?.nameKanji.trim() ? 'error' : ''}`}
                value={user?.nameKanji}
                // onInput={(e) => setUser({ ...user, nameKanji: e.target.value })}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange('nameKanji', e.target.value)}

              />
            </div>
            {!user?.nameKanji || !user?.nameKanji.trim() ? (
              <p className="form-input-error px-3">{t('SPOT.REQUIRED')}</p>
            ) : <></>}
          </div>


        <p className="my-page-info-section-title">{t('SPOT.CONFIRM_NAME_KANA')}</p>

        <div className="form-input">
            <div className="row top gap px-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className={`user-info full ${!user?.nameKana || !user?.nameKana.trim() ? 'error' : ''}`}
                value={user?.nameKana}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange('nameKana', e.target.value)}

                // onInput={(e) => setUser({ ...user, nameKana: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            {!user?.nameKana || !user?.nameKana.trim() ? (
              <p className="form-input-error px-3">{t('SPOT.REQUIRED')}</p>
            ) : <></>}
          </div>


        <p className="my-page-info-section-title">{t('SPOT.PHONE_NUMBER')}</p>
        <div className="form-input">
            <div className="row top gap px-3">
              <input
                type="number"
                className={`user-info full ${phoneNumberError ? 'error' : ''}`}
                value={user?.phoneNumber}
                onInput={onPhoneNumberInput}
              />
            </div>
            {!!phoneNumberError && (
              <p className="form-input-error px-3">{t('SPOT.PHONE_NUMBER_FORMAT')}</p>
            )}
          </div>

       

        <p className="my-page-info-section-title">{t('SPOT.POSTAL_CODE')}</p>
         <div className="form-input">
            <div className="row top gap px-3">
              <input
                type="number"
                className={`user-info full ${postalCodeError ? 'error' : ''}`}
                value={user?.postalCode}
                onInput={onPostalCodeInput}
              />
            </div>
            {!!postalCodeError && (
              <p className="form-input-error px-3">{t('SPOT.POSTAL_CODE_FORMAT')}</p>
            )}
          </div>
      


        <p className="my-page-info-section-title">{t('SPOT.PREFECTURE')}</p>
        <div className="form-input">
            <div className="row top gap px-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className={`user-info full ${!user?.prefecture || !user?.prefecture.trim() ? 'error' : ''}`}
                value={user?.prefecture}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange('prefecture', e.target.value)}

                // onInput={(e) => setUser({ ...user, prefecture: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            {!user?.prefecture || !user?.prefecture.trim() ? (
              <p className="form-input-error px-3">{t('SPOT.REQUIRED')}</p>
            ) : <></>}
          </div>
       


        <p className="my-page-info-section-title">{t('SPOT.CITY')}</p>
         <div className="form-input">
            <div className="row top gap px-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className={`user-info full ${!user?.city || !user?.city.trim() ? 'error' : ''}`}
                value={user?.city}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange('city', e.target.value)}

                // onInput={(e) => setUser({ ...user, city: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            {!user?.city || !user?.city.trim() ? (
              <p className="form-input-error px-3">{t('SPOT.REQUIRED')}</p>
            ) : <></>}
          </div>


        <p className="my-page-info-section-title">{t('SPOT.STREET_ADDRESS')}</p>
        <div className="form-input">
            <div className="row top gap px-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className={`user-info full ${!user?.street_address || !user?.street_address.trim() ? 'error' : ''}`}
                value={user?.street_address}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange('street_address', e.target.value)}
                // onInput={(e) => setUser({ ...user, street_address: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            {!user?.street_address || !user?.street_address.trim() ? (
              <p className="form-input-error px-3">{t('SPOT.REQUIRED')}</p>
            ) : <></>}
          </div>

)
```

Could anyone suggest / help me on this one , i've been trying to debug this since 2 days , but nothing helpful found.

thank you

Comment: Try to reduce it down to it simplest form, and a CodeSandbox would help greatly with communal debugging.